# ashx - get all the possible items of QueryString

Tags: asp.net, ashx

Looking at this
http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx

I might have bits of code like this:

```
string file = context.Request.QueryString["file"];
if (file == "logo")
{
    r.WriteFile("Logo1.png");
}
else
{
    r.WriteFile("Flower1.png");
}
```

That should allow me to see different things depending on URL that I enter in a browser, for example:

```
http://www.dotnetperls.com/?file=logo
http://www.dotnetperls.com/?file=sth_else_eg_flower
```

The problem I am facing now is how, knowing just `http://www.dotnetperls.com/?file` can I read what the all the assumed options of the `file` variable are? In this case it would be "logo" and anything else.

What I have in reality is `http://www.somewebstie.com/somefile.ashx?somevariable=`. I can Google up the string to get few results (i.e. `http://www.somewebstie.com/somefile.ashx?somevariable=abcde` or `http://www.somewebstie.com/somefile.ashx?somevariable=xyz`) thus I know it exists and is somehow searchable. I just would like to know all the other "abcde" and "xyz". If I try just `http://www.somewebstie.com/somefile.ashx` I get a singe line error saying that I am giving a wrong variable and I cannot see anything important in the source of the site.

What might be important here - I have zero knowledge about web technologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get this information. Its all hidden in the code implementation. There is no published format (by default) that will show you all of the available options the code is looking for.

Comment: Why is Google able to give me some results?

Comment: Google is able to see all the urls that people enter into their browser. It doesn't give you necessarily what are correct or even all options. Google has no idea what the code is behind the scenes (you can't - there's no way to determine if a coder has written if(file=="logo"). Thats hidden in code.